# how to change comment header in particular node type in sub theme in drupal 7 using comment-wrapper-<content-type>.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Hi I am new to Drupal Development.
I am trying to alter comment section of article content.
My requirement is I want to change the header in [Comment Section]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1QZZ.png) from **Add New Comments** to to **add new review** and **comments** to **previous reviews** ,and **subject** to **review subject** in my subtheme which uses bartik as base theme.

Can anyone help me.
Here is the code which I altered in comment-wrapper-article.tpl.php in sub theme.But I can't alter the display.

```
<?php
<div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php if ($node->type == 'article'): && $node->type == 'article');?>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<h2 class="title"><?php print t('previous Reviews'); ?></h2>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($content['comments']  ?>
<?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
<h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add New Review'); ?></h2>
<?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
?>
```

Comment: A small suggestion: don't open/close so many php tags, instead open it once, store all outputs in a variable and then echo it once. By doing that, you will also find the problem in your code.

Comment: @DainisAbols thanks for the tip but even the core templates code is of similar kind with multiple php tags am I missing something regarding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had Succeed in getting the solution to the problem, in case if any one faces the same problem.Here is the solution.

```
<div id="comments" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php if ($content['comments'] && $node->type != 'forum'): ?>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<h2 class="title"><?php print t('Previous Reviews'); ?></h2>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
<?php if ($content['comment_form']): ?>
<h2 class="title comment-form"><?php print t('Add New Review'); ?></h2>
<?php print render($content['comment_form']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

the main requirement is the file name should be in the following format."comment-wrapper--node-contenttype.tpl.php"